# Unable to schedule Quartz job

Tags: spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I have written a small `Spring Boot` service using `Quartz`. I am trying to schedule a job using the code below. However, I am repeatedly getting the following error:

```
ERROR[my-service] [2017-01-22 17:38:37,328] [] [main] [SpringApplication]: Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'schedulerFactoryBean' defined in class path resource [com/myservice/configuration/QuartzConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't store trigger 'group1.trigger1' for 'group1.job1' job:The job (group1.job1) referenced by the trigger does not exist. [See nested exception: org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: The job (group1.job1) referenced by the trigger does not exist.]
```

Needless to say, the job never gets scheduled. Here is the relevant code:

```
@Slf4j
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TimedJob implements Job {
    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        log.debug("**********timed job****************");
    }
}

@Configuration
public class QuartzConfiguration {
...
    @Inject
    MyDao myDao;

    @Bean
    public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws SchedulerException {

        SchedulerFactoryBean factory = new SchedulerFactoryBean();

        factory.setAutoStartup(true);
        factory.setOverwriteExistingJobs(true);

        QuartzJobFactory jobFactory = new QuartzJobFactory();
        jobFactory.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        factory.setJobFactory(jobFactory);

        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.setSchedulerContextAsMap(Collections.singletonMap("my_dao", myDao));

        JobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob()
                .ofType(TimedJob.class)
                .storeDurably()
                .withDescription("desc")
                .withIdentity("job1", "group1")
                .build();

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
        Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
                .newTrigger()
                .startAt(calendar.getTime())
                .withSchedule(
                        SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().withIntervalInSeconds(1).repeatForever()
                )
                .forJob(jobDetail)
                .withIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
                .build();
        factory.setTriggers(trigger);

        Properties quartzProperties = new Properties();
        quartzProperties.setProperty("org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName", instanceName);
        quartzProperties.setProperty("org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId", instanceId);
        quartzProperties.setProperty("org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount", threadCount);
        quartzProperties.setProperty("org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass", driverDelegateClassName);
        factory.setQuartzProperties(quartzProperties);

        factory.start();

        return factory;
    }
```

This is almost exactly copied from the Quartz tutorials [here](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-02.html). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try to use '@EnableScheduling' to autoconfigure and use '@Scheduled' annotation on method run as an alternative

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need setting your jobDetail to your factory instance.

The below URL might help you.
http://www.baeldung.com/spring-quartz-schedule